# Как  образовать прилагательное?

Tags: словообразование, грамотная-речь

Когда мы говорим о периоде времени от вечера до ночи, мы можем сказать "вечерне-ночной", если в течение утра и дня, то "утренне-дневной". То есть, например, "Он перечитал плоды своих вечерне-ночных трудов". А как быть, если те же "труды" производились в период с ночи до утра? Можно ли сказать "ночно-утренний"? Или "ноче-утренний"? Как-то очень режут глаз оба эти оборота.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что здесь следует отметить два момента.

Во-первых, нет потребности в таком слове, так как обычно в этом случае говорят о ночных трудах.

Во-вторых, даже в качестве авторского слова вариант "ночно-утренний" не подойдет. Дело в том, что такое сложное слово трудно произнести в связи с тем, что  оно имеет второе (вспомогательное) ударение на первом слоге.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласен с Софией: в таких случаях обычно используется прилагательное ночной.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, не надо мудрствовать. Пусть будут труды ночные, вечерние, утренние и дневные